# Dockerizing a proxy server so I could connect to the container via vhost. Is it possible?

Tags: docker, nginx

At the moment I have a Docker container that consists of a LAMP stack (PHP, Apache, MySQL). It is working fine on http://localhost:my_specified_port. However, I want to access it via http://some_domain.dev. My current solution is to have NGINX on local as a proxy and doing:

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name  some_domain.dev
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:my_specified_port;
    }
}
```

It is working fine. However, I want to make it easier for my coworkers, and dockerize the NGINX server and have the same result. Is it possible to do it? I can't find any solutions online. Thanks a lot.

**EDIT:** Big edit. I forgot to mention, that I want NGINX in docker work on another port than 80. So if some people have apache installed on their local, it would still work.

Comment: This is called "dockerize nginx". If you Google it, you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.  https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+dockerize+nginx&oq=how+to+dockerize+nginx&aqs=chrome..69i57.3152j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @bbozo You are right. I forgot to mention one big thing. Please see the edit. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### 90% solution

A starting point to solve this would be to use [jwilder/nginx-proxy](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy) - a dockerized Nginx reverse proxy. It automates the procedure you described in the question, by generating Nginx configuration depending on other containers' env vars.

And you need a way to point your domain to resolve through the Nginx reverse proxy. The most common way is to use `/etc/hosts`. The route would look like:

- Browser searches for domain
- `/etc/hosts` says the domain resolves to ip of reverse proxy
- Reverse proxy checks if the domain exists in it settings
- Reverse proxy forwards the request to appropriate container

But because you want Nginx reverse proxy to run on a port other than 80, you will still need to access the wanted domain with a port. So this solution is not 100% what you want, but it is still a good starting point to understand how to mock domain names with the use of a reverse proxy:

- run `docker run -d -p 8080:80 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro jwilder/nginx-proxy`
- add env var `VIRTUAL_HOST=some_domain.dev` to your LAMP container (you can also use `VIRTUAL_PORT={{any port number}}` if your app inside the container runs on a different port than 80)
- add `127.0.0.1 some_domain.dev` to `/etc/hosts`
- access `http://some_domain.dev:8080`

If later you would want to add another containerized app with a different domain, you should:

- add env var `VIRTUAL_HOST=another_domain.dev` to your new app's container
- add `127.0.0.1 another_domain.dev` to `/etc/hosts`
- access `http://another_domain.dev:8080`

---

#### 100% solution

If you want to mock domain names in a maintainable way that can scale across a development team - you can use `jwilder/nginx-proxy` together with [mitm-nginx-proxy-companion](https://github.com/artemkloko/docker-mitm-nginx-proxy-companion) and a browser proxy extension. `mitm-nginx-proxy-companion` includes `mitmproxy` and a dns server, which allows it to send "local domains requests" to the reserve proxy and the rest of requests to the "real" internet.

After the setup, the whole route of will look like this:

- You try to access a domain in the browser.
- The proxy extension forwards that request to mitmproxy instead of the "real" internet.
- mitmproxy tries to resolve the domain name through the dns server in the same container.

  - If the domain is not a "local" one, it will forward the request to the "real" internet.
  - But if the domain is a "local" one, it will forward the request to the reverse proxy.
- The reverse proxy in its turn forwards the request to the appropriate container that includes the service we want to access.

With `mitm-nginx-proxy-companion` you do not need to use `/etc/hosts`, so if you tried the first solution, you should remove the entries that you added before. I am adding the solution in a [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/) form for the ease of writing/reading it

```
version: '3.3'

services:

  lamp:
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: some_domain.dev
      VIRTUAL_PORT: 9999
    image: my_lamp_image

  another_app:
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: another_domain.dev
    image: my_app_image

  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    labels:
      - "mitmproxy.proxyVirtualHosts=true"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro

  nginx-proxy-mitm:
    dns:
      - 127.0.0.1
    image: artemkloko/mitm-nginx-proxy-companion
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
```

Then you would need to

- Run `docker-compose up`
- Add a proxy extension to your browser, with proxy address being `127.0.0.1:8080`
- Access `http://some_domain.dev`
- Access `http://another_domain.dev`

**Note**: I am the author of `mitm-nginx-proxy-companion`